# Cannot configure TERMIOS in SOCAT, xioinitialize: Assertion

Tags: linux, assert, powerpc, termios, socat

I am using SOCAT 1.7.2.4 from Yocto with PowerPC as target (Big Endian) on a Linux machine. Not able to start SOCAT as I am getting the below assertion

```
xioinitialize.c:45: xioinitialize: Assertion `3 << opt_crdly.arg3 == 00030000' failed.
```

I commented out the assert in xioinitialize.c and I get the below assertion

```
xioinitialize.c:45: xioinitialize: Assertion `3 << opt_tabdly.arg3 == 00006000' failed.
```

When I bypass this assert, I am greeted by the next one

```
xioinitialize.c:45: xioinitialize: Assertion `3 << opt_csize.arg3 == 00001400' failed.
```

If I skip all these, I can run SOCAT fine. How do I get rid of these asserts ? I run SOCAT on x86/Ubuntu target and don't see these assertions. If I disable termios on PowerPC target, I can run SOCAT (but I need termios support). When I search online I see this https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/5210 post which mentions this issue was fixed 5 years back.

Answer (score 0):

Well the link you mention leads to this other [link](https://dev.openwrt.org/changeset/26728), which states:

> This does ONLY happen in a cross compiling environment, otherwise the
>   configure script guesses them right.

Are you sure you did compile SOCAT properly ? I would setup a debian machine instead, and use the SOCAT [package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/socat) directly.

If you want to quickly test the binary, you can also do:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/socat/socat_1.7.2.4-2_powerpc.deb
$ ar x socat_1.7.2.4-2_powerpc.deb 
$ tar xf data.tar.xz
$ ./usr/bin/socat
```

You'll need to make sure you have the proper dependencies, eg. **libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0)** and **libwrap0 (>= 7.6)**. To double check simply check the output of:

```
$ ldd ./usr/bin/socat
```

Comment: I am compiling SOCAT properly, the issue is with the variables CRDLY, TBDLY and CSIZE. The default value in the recipe is 9, 11, 14 respectively which won't work for me. I was able to get SOCAT working by modifying these values but not sure of the significance of them.

Comment: In this case, how do you explain that `socat` works on Debian/PowerPC ?

Comment: You might have used socat for PowerPC target, but are executing the socat binary on a PowerPC target ? As mentioned in the earlier post, maybe configure is not initializing the environment correctly. CRDLY, TBDLY and CSIZE were specified in the recipe as arguments instead of configure setting these variables for the PowerPC target.